# How can i find the length of a line between two points with coordinates (x1, y1) and (x2, y2) in array?

Tags: c, for-loop, while-loop

How can i find the length of a line between two points with coordinates (x1, y1) and (x2, y2) in array ? For example i have 2 arrays : arrayX[10] and arrayY[10].

I have to find the results of the following operations in the loop and save them in the result array :

`sqrt((arrayX[0]- arrayX[1])^2+(arrayY[0]-arrayY[1]^2))`

`sqrt((arrayX[1]- arrayX[2])^2+(arrayY[1]-arrayY[2]^2))`

.

.

.

Comment: Here is [hypot()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/hypot-hypotf-hypotl-hypot-hypotf-hypotl?view=msvc-160) function. That ensures the squaring is done *after* the subtraction too.

Answer (score 2):

In C there is no exponentiation operator. To compute `x^2` either use `x * x` or `pow(x, 2)` from `math.h`.

Possible solution

```
double dist[9];
for (int i = 0; i + 1 < 10; ++i) {
   double dx = arrayX[i]- arrayX[i + 1];
   double dy = arrayY[i]- arrayY[i + 1];
   dist[i] = sqrt(dx *dx + dy * dy);
}
```